# connecting server nodes to one network, reach services by one of the IP's

Tags: networking, service, ip, cluster-computing, iptables

I have 2 servers, `vps1.xxx.com` and `vps2.xxx.com`.

I host services on both nodes.
I want to only use `vps1.xxx.com` to access all services, also the services on `vps2.xxx.com`.

So, e.g. a service on `vps2:8040` should be reachable by: `vps1.xxx.com:8040`

! I can't use nginx as a proxy.

Does someone have an idea, how I could realize this behavior?

Greetings :)

Comment: you can use `ncat`. the man page has several examples on how to achieve this.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet thanks, the man said this will work: `ncat --sh-exec "ncat vps2.xxx.com 8040" -l 8040 --keep-open --no-shutdown` thanks, awesome! but i want to get the IP of the issuer requesting vps1 at vps2, not the vps1 ip at the 8040-service on vps2 then .... how to reach that?